# Database creation failure, result Undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to create a simple nodejs code using express and mysql.

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'admin',
    password : ''
});

db.connect((err) => {
    if(err){
        console.log('Error while connecting');
    }
    console.log('Connected');
});     

const app = express();


app.get('/createdb',(req, res) => {

    let sql = 'CREATE DATABASE nodemysql';
    db.query(sql,(err,result) => {
        if(err){
            console.log("error while creating database");

        }
        console.log('result: '+result);
        res.send('database created..');
    });
});

app .listen('4200',() => {
    console.log('Server started on port 4200');
});
```

The response is sent to the browser that says

> database created..

but the result it throws is undefined. Also the console that says

> Error while creating database is printed

Error I am getting is

> [nodemon] restarting due to changes... 
>    [nodemon] restarting due to
>   changes... [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
>   Server started on port 4200
>   Connected error while creating database 
>    result: undefined

I am not sure on what I am missing out. Please help.

Comment: as a suggestion, use [CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS nodemysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-database.html)

Comment: Tried. It dint work.

Comment: Was the database actually created? What happens when this is executed within a SQL client using the same authentication?

Comment: Can u share the MySQL error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code should work fine, try to execute the below code in a .js file. If it works, then we would be sure that nothing wrong in the conf part.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "root"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  con.query("CREATE DATABASE mydb", function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Database created");
  });
});
```

Comment: Then there is a problem in ur configuration part.

Comment: Ok, so how i find out what the problem is? I am very new to database so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I have added a new answer..follow the steps there

Comment: It worked. But the result is [object object]. Why am i not getting any fields in there?

Comment: Sorry didnt get it!

Comment: According to  the video I was refering to, result is supposed to be giving me fields such as message, protocol, warning count, changedRows etc. But I get it as [object object].

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, but added the keyword 'function', like below:

```
app.get('/createdb',(req, res) => {

    let sql = 'CREATE DATABASE nodemysql11';
    db.query(sql, function(err,result) => {
        if(err){
            console.log("error while creating database");

        }
        console.log('result: '+result);
        res.send('database created..');
    });
});
```

Comment: Adding the keyword function is throwing an error.  Are there any other changes to be made if we need to add the function keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work

```
app.get('/createdb',(req, res) => {

db.query('CREATE DATABASE nodemysql11', function(err,result)  {
    if(err){
        console.log("error while creating database");

    }
    console.log('result: '+result);
    res.send('database created..');
});
```

});

Comment: No. I still get the same result undefined error. The database is not created.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below line and then run the .js file.
I assume u have done `npm install mysql`

```
mv ./node_modules/node-mysql/node_modules/* ./node_modules/
```

Comment: yes, i have done npm install mysql. but it still cant find the path specified. I have a mysql folder inside nodemodules, but node-mysql does not exist yet.